# paypal return URL and Java @RequestParam: missing parameters

Tags: java, spring, paypal

In my Java Spring Roo web application I try to integrate PayPal Express Checkout.
I do get to the PayPal website and have my transaction processed.
Yet when retrieving the RETURN URL from Paypal they do not get properly recognized and the success page. It seems that there are parameters before the ? (question mark).

This is what I get back from PayPal:
http://localhost:8080//paypal/success&userId=2&itemId=5?token=EC-8W2450105U799570F&PayerID=VGHU6332LAEW8

As you can see there are 2 parameters before the ?.
When processing the URL with Spring (Roo) using

```
    @RequestMapping(produces = "text/html")
public String success(
        @RequestParam(value = "userId", required = false) String userId, 
        @RequestParam(value = "itemId", required = false) String itemId, 
        @RequestParam(value = "token", required = false) String token, 
        @RequestParam(value = "PayerID", required = false) String PayerID, 
        Model uiModel) {
```

Only the last 2 parameters are found: token and PayerID
I think this is because parameters are normally found behind the ? (question mark).

For processing with PayPal I use [Integrating PayPal for Digital Goods from Northway games](http://northwaygames.com/integrating-paypal-for-digital-goods/). In this implementation the userId en ItemID are send to Paypal. I do not know if that is causing the trouble.

**Questions**

1. Why is PayPal returning parameters before the ? (question mark)?
2. How can I solve this problem, how can I get the other parameters?
3. What is the cleanest solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

In the PayPalManager.java class I used from Northway games the returnURL is:

```
RETURN_URL + "&userId=" + userId + "&itemId=" + itemId);
```

After changing it to

```
RETURN_URL + "?userId=" + userId + "&itemId=" + itemId);
```

the problem was solved.

Mark the ? (question mark before userId)